# "Twig_Error_Loader: Template "file.html.twig" is not defined" for new twig template file

Tags: theming, 8, drush, caching, debugging

After creating a new paragraph type and its template file in the correct folder location, I am receiving the following error every time I view the page with that houses the new paragraph type.

**Twig_Error_Loader: Template "file.html.twig" is not defined (Drupal\Core\Template\Loader\ThemeRegistryLoader: Unable to find template "file.html.twig" in the Drupal theme registry.)**

I have followed the steps [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2598914) to disable the cache. However I don't believe it worked because I still have to clear my cache through config>performance for changes to twig files to appear.

Similarly, I tried to enable twig debugging (and turn off caching) [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/debugging-compiled-twig-templates) and can not confirm that it has been enabled either.

I found an article: blog.wturrell.co.uk/troubleshooting-drupalcoretemplateloaderthemeregistryloader-unable-to-find-template/ discussing potentially clearing the theme-registry, but I do not have access to drush to run any commands.

I have already tried clearing all the cache from within drupal itself.

Answer (score 2):

Cache is a pretty broad concept, and sometimes mean content caching and sometimes they mean broader things like config settings and the theme registry.  Disabling content caching is still a bit confusing to me so I can't help with that part of the question.

But the theme registry has some pretty simple rules.  If you add new template file (or change it's name or move it to a different folder) or if you add a new theme callback (in hook_theme) or override to a theme callback (hook_preprocess...) then you MUST clear the theme registry before they will be active.  To do that, the simplest method (without additional modules or drush) is to 'Clear all caches' under admin->config->development->performance.

Of note, sometimes the theme registry is referred to as the theme cache.  While I know it's probably possible, I don't think that disabling the theme registry from caching is a standard practice in development.